# AngularJS Form Validation and Submit

Tags: angularjs

Codepen link: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/mVyPaw

Need to create an angular app (w/ 1 controller) that validates that this form has all three fields filled out & Submit button can only be enabled if the form is valid. Don't need to use the preprocessors.

```
<div class="container" ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="formCtrl">

  <h1><span><img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/15309/angular-logo.svg" alt="Angular.js Logo" /></span> Angular.js - Web Form</h1>

  <form role="form" name="form" id="contact-form">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="FirstName">First name</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" name="FirstName" id="FirstName" placeholder="enter first name" ng-model="firstName">
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="LastName">Last Name</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" name="LastName" id="LastName" placeholder="enter last name" ng-model="lastName">
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="EmailAddress">Email address</label>
      <input type="email" class="form-control" id="EmailAddress" name="EmailAddress" placeholder="enter email" ng-model="emailAddress" ng-model-options="{ updateOn: 'blur' }">
    </div>

    <div class="checkbox">
      <label>
        <input type="checkbox" required> Check me out
      </label>
    </div>

    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" ng-model="submitButton">Submit</button>

  </form>

</div>
```

Comment: Did you try to use validation?

Comment: see my updated answer

Comment: I'm kinda new to Angular so not sure how to do that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually it's module inject problem.  `ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="formCtrl"` Where is your `myApp` module code.

try like this.

```
<div class="container" ng-app>

  <h1><span><img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/15309/angular-logo.svg" alt="Angular.js Logo" /></span> Angular.js - Web Form</h1>

  <form role="form" name="form" id="contact-form" novalidate>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="FirstName">First name</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" name="FirstName" id="FirstName" placeholder="enter first name" ng-model="firstName" required>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="LastName">Last Name</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" name="LastName" id="LastName" placeholder="enter last name" ng-model="lastName" required>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="EmailAddress">Email address</label>
      <input type="email" class="form-control" id="EmailAddress" name="EmailAddress" placeholder="enter email" ng-model="emailAddress" ng-model-options="{ updateOn: 'blur' }" required>
    </div>

    <div class="checkbox">
      <label>
        <input type="checkbox" required> Check me out
      </label>
    </div>


    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" ng-disabled="form.$invalid">Submit</button>

  </form>

</div>
```

Comment: Assume angular library is already included (1.3.0) on this codepen

Comment: What if you want to have the bootstrap enhanced error messaging as well? This seems to get rid of that

Answer (score 0):

Add required validation

```
 <div class="container" ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="formCtrl">

  <h1><span><img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/15309/angular-logo.svg" alt="Angular.js Logo" /></span> Angular.js - Web Form</h1>

  <form role="form" name="myForm" id="contact-form">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="FirstName">First name</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" name="FirstName" id="FirstName" placeholder="enter first name" ng-model="firstName" required>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="LastName">Last Name</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" name="LastName" id="LastName" placeholder="enter last name" ng-model="lastName" required >
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="EmailAddress">Email address</label>
      <input type="email" class="form-control" id="EmailAddress" name="EmailAddress" placeholder="enter email" ng-model="emailAddress" ng-model-options="{ updateOn: 'blur' }" required>
    </div>

    <div class="checkbox">
      <label>
        <input type="checkbox" required> Check me out
      </label>
    </div>

    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" ng-model="submitButton" data-ng-disabled="myForm.$invalid" >Submit</button>

  </form>

</div>
```

Here is your edited [CodePen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/VbQByP)

Comment: Thanks guys! Why is it wrong @ManikandanVelayutham? Seems to work for me

Comment: Do F12 then you can know.

Comment: Hello the button should not clickable